# Learning Algebraic Number theory

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, self-learning, book-recommendation

I am looking for a good reference to self study algebraic number theory, as no undergraduate course is given at the university. I've web-searched a lot of online notes and courses, and I don't seem to understand what's happening. Could anyone who took/is taking/teaching a course in algebraic number theory say what are the prerequisites and the corequisites to tackle the subject in an efficient way? Further, could anyone suggest a good reference to learn the subject?

Comment: This question is not answerable. There are ANT courses with any number of different prerequisites. Moreover, it would be interesting why you want  to study ANT.

Comment: "Introductory Algebraic Number theory, Alaca" is elementary and very detailed. "Algebraic Theory of Numbers, Samuel" still elementary but more elegant. "Number Fields, Marcus" wonderful exercise oriented introduction. In any case, you need to pair this up with an abstract algebra textbook that covers basic rings and Galois theory, e.g. Fraleigh!

Comment: I would recommend Pierre Samuel's little book: *Algebraic Theory of Numbers*. You can take a look at this scanned copy [on this site](http://www.google.fr/url?url=http://interact.sagemath.org/edu/2010/581b/books/samuel-algebraic_theory_of_numbers.pdf&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ei=9RJrVf-6BormsASziYHoCw&ved=0CBwQFjAB&sig2=4V4RqJZqfjc99CXimyYEDg&usg=AFQjCNENBRdBcZ4bSWc7sd2yxz0Q3a0Y5Q)

Comment: I never finished reading it but I heard neukirch is a good introduction.

Answer (score 1):

At the University of New South Wales (UNSW), which is considered to house the best school of mathematics in Australia, we have a third-year undergraduate course entitled *Algebraic Techniques in Number Theory*.

Having read the [course outline](https://www.maths.unsw.edu.au/sites/default/files/math3521s12015.pdf), it appears that a background of linear algebra and discrete mathematics comes in handy.

Unfortunately, they don't recommend any textbooks as the course is self-contained, and claim that any textbook on number theory would be useful. However, it appears as though *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory* by Ireland and Rosen is a popular choice.

Answer (score 1):

*Algebraic Number Theory* by Jarvis could be a good option. It has an appendix containing extensive hints and solutions to the exercises (handy for self-study) and has modest prerequisites: linear algebra, some elementary number theory and parts of abstract algebra (groups up to Lagrange's theorem and some acquaintance with rings and fields). It's aimed at advanced undergraduates.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** A bit more advanced is Neukirch, "Algebraic Number Theory". You need background in commutative algebra (Atiyah-Macdonald or Matsumura). Its a good book.